# Move implementation in C

Tags: c, macros, initialization, move

I'm trying to implement a move function to be able to sort of move objects without copying their contents. Here is what I mean:

```
static void foo(const char* moved_content){
   //use moved_content
}

const char *string = //...
foo(string);
string = NULL;
```

So after I pass the `string` to `foo` no one else can access the string. I think this will make debugging easier in case of illegal access since e.g. on Linux I'm mostly likely to receive `SEGV`.

I tried the following:

```
static inline void* move(void **ptr){
    void *tmp = *ptr;
    *ptr = NULL;
    return tmp;
}
```

But I cannot use it like, say

```
const char *str = "string";
const char *moved = (char*) (move((void **)&str)); //this is non-conforming
```

I tried to write a macro using gcc extension but this seem no way to return a value from it:

```
#define MOVE(ptr) \
    do { \
        __typeof__(ptr) original_ptr = ptr; \
        __typeof__(*original_ptr) tmp = *original_ptr; \
        *ptr = NULL; \
    } while(0)
```

Is there a way to implement it conformingly? Probably `_Generic` is a way to go... Or explicitly setting the pointer to `NULL` is not that bad?

Comment: What do you mean with "*is non-conforming*"?

Comment: @alk I mean it's UB. We can cast pointers to object types to each other only if they have the same alignment requirements `6.3.2.3(p7)`. But the `6.2.5(p28)` specifies that `char **` and `void **` does not have to have the same  representation/alignement requirements.

Comment: Do you really prefer `const char *moved = (char*) (move((void **)&str));` over `const char *moved = str; str = NULL;` ?

Comment: @4386427 Have to agree... this looks crazy. My intention was to avoid setting pointer to `NULL` boilerplate so I tried to generalize the solution to be reusable.

Comment: Why not simply do: `#define MOVE(dptr, sptr) \
    do { \
        dptr = sptr; \
        sptr = NULL; \
    } while(0)` and use it like `MOVE(p2, p1);` It is a common style that C programmers know from a number of std functions.

Comment: @4386427 Probably because it does not serve as an initialiser to a `const bla` pointer?

Comment: @4386427 Looks like a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @alk hmm... true, that would be a problem with my suggestion

Comment: Are… are you sure you want to write C?

Comment: @alk But if we initialize to `const bla` pointer wouldn't the compiler warns about different qualification?

Comment: @Ry- For now I cannot switch to some other language unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems you are willing to use extensions to the C language, your 2nd approach is almost there, just you need to go one step further by making it a "[*Statement Expression*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)":

```
#define MOVE_AND_CLEAN(p) ( \
  { \
    __typeof__(p) p_tmp = p; \
    p = NULL; \
    p_tmp; \
  } \
)
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char * ps = "string";
  const char * pd = MOVE_AND_CLEAN(ps); 

  printf("ps = %p\npd = %p\n", (void*)ps, (void*)pd);
}
```

and get:

```
ps = 0x0
pd = 0x123456789
```

:-)